# Iterate over NSMutableArray that contains strings

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I add strings to an NSMutableArray and now I want to iterate that array:

```
    NSEnumerator *e = [numbers objectEnumerator];
    id object;

    NSMutableString* theString = [NSMutableString string];

    while (object = [e nextObject]) {
        [theString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i;", object]];
    }
```

But actually object does not seem to be the string I added to the array but just a number. How can I get the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"%i"` is the format string for an integer, so it's treating the object's address as an integer. The format for an object is `"%@"`.

Answer (score 2):

Just append the string. No need for (expensive) format conversion.

```
NSMutableString *theString = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSString *number in numbers)
    [theString appendString:number];
```

Comment: That should not be "while", but "for".